# numpy roll produce a unnecessary horizontal line

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following python code where I read from a CSV file a produce a plot. My goal is to shift the data in X-axis by some extend however the x axis is phase (between 0 - 1) and shifting in this context means rolling the elements (thats why I use numpy roll). My problem is that when I use numpy roll, It produces some unnecessary line along the x axis (the red plot). How can I get rid of this?

```
data = np.genfromtxt('radio.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

rad_ph = data[:, 0]  
rad_pp = data[:, 1]

bin_normalized = rad_ph / max(rad_ph)

shift = 0.85 
bin_shifted = np.roll(bin_normalized, int(shift / np.diff(bin_normalized)[0]))

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8)) 
ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(bin_normalized, (rad_pp*50), linestyle='-',color='b', label='Normal', linewidth=2) 
ax.plot(bin_shifted, (rad_pp*50), linestyle='-',color='#9a2462', label='shifted', linewidth=2)

plt.legend(prop={'size': 16}) 
plt.savefig('PP_overplot_radio.pdf' , dpi=300)
```

[image]

For the record, I also tried shift both the bin_normalized and rad_pp arrays, and then plot the shifted data,

```
rad_pp_shifted = np.roll(rad_pp, int(shift / np.diff(bin_normalized)[0]))
ax.plot(bin_shifted, (rad_pp_shifted*50), linestyle='-', color='#9a2462', label='shifted', linewidth=2, drawstyle='steps-post')
```

As well as using slicing instead of np.roll, and then plot the shifted data using plt.step instead of plt.plot but it didnt work either.

```
shift = 0.85
shift_idx = int(shift / np.diff(bin_normalized)[0])
bin_shifted = np.concatenate((bin_normalized[shift_idx:], bin_normalized[:shift_idx]))
rad_pp_shifted = np.concatenate((rad_pp[shift_idx:], rad_pp[:shift_idx]))

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = plt.subplot()

ax.step(bin_normalized, (rad_pp*50), where='post', linestyle='-', color='b', label='Normal', linewidth=2)
ax.step(bin_shifted, (rad_pp_shifted*50), where='post', linestyle='-', color='#9a2462', label='shifted', linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Look at the `bin_shifted` values.  Do you see a jump from 1 to 0 in the middle?    Imagine plotting y [1,2,3,4] against a x [2 3 0 1].  What' the connecting line going to look like?  Your `concatenate` appears to the same thing.  I'd suggest practicing with some simpler plots; we can't replicate your plots with data loaded from the `csv`.  Make sure you understand what you want to show before fishing around randomly for solutions.

Comment: You should shift the y-values, not the x-values.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by the boundary condition used in `numpy.roll`, By default, `numpy.roll` uses a circular boundary condition and it can cause the last element in the array to be wrapped around to the beginning which can cause a problem. Use the `mode` parameter in `numpy.roll`.

edit: I modified my answer for using an alternative method (array slicing) to shift the array that does not rely on the mode parameter, or you could use `numpy` version 1.26.0 or later

```
data = np.genfromtxt('radio.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

rad_ph = data[:, 0]  
rad_pp = data[:, 1]

bin_normalized = rad_ph / max(rad_ph)

shift = 0.85 
shift_idx = int(shift / np.diff(bin_normalized)[0])
bin_shifted = np.concatenate((bin_normalized[shift_idx:], bin_normalized[:shift_idx]))
rad_pp_shifted = np.concatenate((rad_pp[shift_idx:], rad_pp[:shift_idx]))

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8)) 
ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(bin_normalized, (rad_pp*50), linestyle='-', color='b', label='Normal', linewidth=2) 
ax.plot(bin_shifted, (rad_pp_shifted*50), linestyle='-', color='#9a2462', label='shifted', linewidth=2)

plt.legend(prop={'size': 16}) 
plt.savefig('PP_overplot_radio.pdf' , dpi=300)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I am getting an error saying: TypeError: _roll_dispatcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'.  I am using Numpy version 1.24.2 with jupyter notebook

Comment: Both of you - look at the `np.roll` docs!  Show me where a `mode` parameter is documented.